# Socket.io: не получается установить соединение на порту 3000

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, node-modules, centos7

Делаю тестовую программу по инструкции https://coderlessons.com/tutorials/kompiuternoe-programmirovanie/uznaite-socket-io/socket-io-kratkoe-rukovodstvo.
Все, как там написано.
app.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.sendfile('index.html');
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
   console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Hello world</title>
   </head>
   <body>Hello world</body>
</html>
```

Сделала все правильно, но ничего не работает (как и всегда и у всех). А если подробнее, то на стороне сервера все ок, nodemon app.js, запущенный в корне сайте, нормально запускается и выдает "listening on *:3000", но если ввести ip_сервера:3000, то "Попытка соединения не удалась. Firefox не может установить соединение с сервером ip_сервера:3000.". index.html не подает приложению нормально или что еще, я не знаю.
Когда я делала приложение на другом серваке, проблем не возникало. Отличие настроек этого сервера от прошлого - разве что в ОС и http-сервере (там Убунту и Апач, здесь - Центос 7 и Энжинкс).
В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Может вам стоит посмотреть какие параметры принимает`listen`?

Comment: @OliverPatterson а что не так?